# Visual Studio 2013 keeps requiring to enter in MS Live username/password for license

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Every few months I get a message that Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate cannot login to download an updated license and I must re-login.  I enter my MS Live account and it updates fine, but I will get the message again in a few months.

Anyway to fix this so it doesn't keep happening?
I am running update 4 which I believe is the latest.

Comment: Perhaps those are just the terms of your license.  Microsoft Support would be the right people to ask about this since they would have access to your details.  Surely typing a password 4 times a year won't kill you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate can only be bought as part of the Dreamspark Premium programme (*only via an educational institution that has bought this package*) or via MSDN.

The licenses for the two methods vary but however both ***require you to re-enter your login details every three months.***
It is auth'ed by a login token, that expires if:

- Three months have passed since it was issued;
- The password for the Windows/Microsoft Account was changed;
- Your licence is revoked;
- [Switching your 'signed-in user'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517673/how-can-i-switch-my-signed-in-user-in-visual-studio-2013?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio logs in using a token, and that token has a limited lifetime. Visual Studio will try to extend the token in the background, but there are a couple of things that could cause the renewal to fail. In such cases you need to log in again to get a fresh token.

Some actions/conditions I know of:

- A wifi-connection that requires form authentication;
- Proxy servers that interfere;
- You choosing the "Log off all sessions" on any Windows account on any site.