# Visual Studio Change Subscription Account

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I would like to change the account used to license my Visual Studio. I've been unable to find a way to change the email used to license it.

I want to avoid reinstalling, as I've made many modifications to the default VS setup.

Is there an option to do this?

Help > Register Product

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Are you trying to change the email address of the account that you already own so that you're effectively updating your email? Or are you trying to re-license a product that formally was registered to someone else, whose Visual Studio account you cannot access???

Comment: I think they just want to install a new/different licence, Jazimov.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19517673/560648 (basically, just sign out and log in as someone else?)

Answer (score 0):

I signed in with the another account, clicked "Check for an updated license", and that did the trick.